# Why do we need a separate structure to hold the 32-bit IPv4 address

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

For socket programming for IPv4 addresses, we have the following structures we need to use in order to set the addresses for the client/server.

```
struct in_addr {

  in_addr_t s_addr; 
};

struct sockaddr_in {
 sa_family_t sin_family;
 in_port_t sin_port;
 
 struct in_addr sin_addr;
 char sin_zero[8];
}
```

My question is why do we need the struct in_addr? Couldn't we just put the in_addr_t field in the sockaddr_in ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's platform-specific. On Windows `in_addr` is defined as the following struct which allows you to access the addresses' individual `byte`s and `short`s ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/ns-winsock2-in_addr)):

```
struct in_addr {
  union {
    struct {
      u_char s_b1;
      u_char s_b2;
      u_char s_b3;
      u_char s_b4;
    } S_un_b;
    struct {
      u_short s_w1;
      u_short s_w2;
    } S_un_w;
    u_long S_addr;
  } S_un;
};
```